# Reduce Task Parallel Library "Boilerplate"

Tags: .net, vb.net, task-parallel-library

My team is using the Task Parallel Library for the first time, and my colleague has come up with some code like what is listed below. We are running a few things, then using that data to make further server requests (the methods with `Async` in the name), and then using the data that comes back from that server call to get even more data. After all of these are loaded, some items on the UI (usually combo boxes) are updated (in the methods with `Returned` in the name), which the user could use for filters.

Basically, we figure out what companies a user has access to, then based on that information, we load some more "filters" for the data (loading some defaults), and then load the data from the default view.

While the code works, it seems like there's a lot of duplicate code, and I was wondering if an extension method or some other code change could be used to reduce the amount of code needed to do something like this.

```
Private Sub GetAndLoadViewData()
    Dim noCancelToken = CancellationToken.None
    Const attachToParent As TaskContinuationOptions = TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent

    Task.Factory.StartNew(
        Sub()
            'fire off child tasks 
            Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() GetCompaniesAsync()).ContinueWith(
                Sub(t As Task(Of List(Of Company))) CompaniesReturned(t), noCancelToken, attachToParent, UiSyncContext)

            Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() GetUserAsync()).ContinueWith(
                Sub(t As Task(Of User)) UserReturned(t), noCancelToken, attachToParent, UiSyncContext)
        End Sub).ContinueWith(
            Sub(prevTask)
                'these tasks depend on the success of the previous task
                If Not prevTask.IsFaulted Then
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() GetFiltersAsync()).ContinueWith(
                        Sub(t As Task(Of List(Of Filter))) FiltersReturned(t), noCancelToken, attachToParent, UiSyncContext)
                Else
                    'Rethrow the exception from the previous task if an exception occurred
                    Throw prevTask.Exception
                End If
            End Sub).ContinueWith(
                Sub(prevTask)
                    'these tasks depend on the success of the previous task
                    If Not prevTask.IsFaulted Then
                        Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() GetDataAsync(CurrentCompany, CurrentFilters)).ContinueWith(
                            Sub(t As Task(Of List(Of Data))) DataReturned(t), noCancelToken, attachToParent, UiSyncContext)

                    Else
                        'Rethrow the exception from the previous task if an exception occurred
                        Throw prevTask.Exception
                    End If
                End Sub).ContinueWith(
                    Sub(prevTask)
                        If prevTask.IsFaulted Then
                            View.HandleFatalException(prevTask.Exception.InnerExceptions.First())
                        Else
                            View.DisplayData()
                        End If
                    End Sub, UiSyncContext)
End Sub
```

I would note that we can only currently use .NET Framework 4.0, due to business reasons.

Let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 1):

I built the [Rackspace Threading Library](https://github.com/rackerlabs/dotnet-threading/releases/latest) for exactly this purpose (open source, Apache 2.0 license).

Another option is using the [Microsoft Async](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) package, allowing you to use `async`/`await` in .NET 4.0 codebases.

---

It's a bit challenging for me to read the code in your post. I've made a few assumptions, in particular that all of your methods that end with `Async` return a `Task` or `Task<T>` (in accordance with the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) guidelines).

Here's what the result might look like with the threading library I mentioned, in C# syntax. The `Then` and `Select` methods behave like regular sequential code - all of the remaining ones are cancelled as soon as an exception is thrown in one. The `Finally` extension method executes regardless of the final state of the antecedent (including cancelled). The `Then` method executes a delegate that returns a `Task`, and then waits for that task to complete (similar to `Unwrap` or your use of `AttachedToParent`). The `Select` method just executes a synchronous block of code that may or may not return a value.

```
Task[] initialTasks =
{
    GetCompaniesAsync().Select(task => CompaniesReturned(task)),
    GetUserAsync().Select(task => UserReturned(task))
}

TaskEx.WhenAll(initialTasks)
    .Then(_ => GetFiltersAsync().Select(task => FiltersReturned(task)))
    .Then(_ => GetDataAsync(CurrentCompany, CurrentFilters).Select(task => DataReturned(task)))
    .Select(_ => View.DisplayData())
    .Finally(
        task =>
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
                View.HandleFatalException(task.Exception.InnerExceptions.First());
        });
```

The `TaskEx.WhenAll` method is not part of the library, but you can implement it like follows:

```
public static Task<Task[]> WhenAll(params Task[] tasks)
{
    return Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, completed => completed);
}
```

Also note that in C#, the various expressions of the form `task => FooReturned(task)` could be replaced with just `FooReturned`, but I chose to leave the longer form so it's clear to readers that `FooReturned` is actually one of your methods that you're calling.